# Change multiple column entries in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large pandas dataframe

```
df.head()

        Year    Average Elo Club    Country Level
0       2017    1283.267334 Kukesi  ALB     0
1       2018    1263.912195 Kukesi  ALB     0
2       2019    1212.714661 Kukesi  ALB     0
3       2020    1231.063379 Kukesi  ALB     0
4       2018    1213.269553 Laci    ALB     0
```

The `Country` column contains abbreviated country codes for 55 countries. I want to change each of these country codes to the full name of the country (for example, `ALB` to `Albania`)

```
df['Country'].unique()

array(['ALB', 'AND', 'ARM', 'AUT', 'AZE', 'BEL', 'BHZ', 'BLR', 'BUL',
       'CRO', 'CYP', 'CZE', 'DEN', 'ENG', 'ESP', 'EST', 'FAR', 'FIN',
       'FRA', 'GEO', 'GER', 'GIB', 'GRE', 'HUN', 'IRL', 'ISL', 'ISR',
       'ITA', 'KAZ', 'KOS', 'LAT', 'LIE', 'LIT', 'LUX', 'MAC', 'MLT',
       'MNT', 'MOL', 'NED', 'NIR', 'NOR', 'POL', 'POR', 'ROM', 'RUS',
       'SCO', 'SLK', 'SMR', 'SRB', 'SUI', 'SVN', 'SWE', 'TUR', 'UKR',
       'WAL'], dtype=object)
```

I have written code that does this for `ALB` specifically:

```
df.Country[df.Country=='ALB'] = 'Albania'
```

Is there a way to do this for all 55 countries?

Comment: You can use `df.Country.map({'ALB': 'Albania', ...})`

Comment: Which standard code (if any) are you following?

Comment: ChatGPT may be able to answer most, if not all, Pandas homework questions. There isn't any need to post it on Stack Overflow. Just to go to ChatGPT directly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`pycountry`](https://pypi.org/project/pycountry/) to craft a dictionary to [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the names from the 3 letter code:

```
import pycountry

mapper = {c.alpha_3: c.name for c in pycountry.countries}
# {'ABW': 'Aruba', 'AFG': 'Afghanistan', 'AGO': 'Angola',
#  'AIA': 'Anguilla', 'ALA': 'Åland Islands', 'ALB': 'Albania',
#  'AND': 'Andorra', ...}

df['Country'] = df['Country'].map(mapper)
```

However your format is not exactly standard, so you could also map from the first 3 letters as a failback:

```
mapper = ({c.name[:3].upper(): c.name for c in pycountry.countries}
         |{c.alpha_3: c.name for c in pycountry.countries}
         )
```